# How to refer to a character group without ambiguity in a regex?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Suppose I want to realize a replacement in a string: `"aabbcc11dd  ee" -> "aabbcc112dd  ee"`, I can use a regex like this within `StringReplace`:

```
RegularExpression["[a-z](\\d+)[a-z]"] -> "$12"
```

well, if only the right-hand side `"$12"` was interpreted as "the group 1 with the digit 2" instead of "the group 12".

So, in Wolfram's regex, is there any syntax setup to eliminate this ambiguity? I know that, for example, in Python there is something like `'\g<i>'`, which, because of the angled brackets, allows no room for ambiguity.

Comment: Not sure, but in general the `StringExpression` and pattern system is actually competitive with regex and allows much more sophisticated binding so I tend to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is this.

```
StringReplace["aabbcc11dd  ee", RegularExpression["(\\d+)"] :> "$1" <> "2"]
```

> `"aabbcc112dd  ee"`

Note the use of `RuleDelayed (:>)` as well as `"$1" <> "2"`.

#### Update

Doing it without `RegularExpression`.

```
StringReplace["aabbcc11dd  ee", x : DigitCharacter .. :> x <> "2"]
```

> `"aabbcc112dd  ee"`

Note that with this approach the equivalent of a regex group is a named character pattern — in this case, `DigitCharacter ..`, the equivalent to regex `\\d+`.

Comment: Great! `~~` works instead of `<>`, too.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ. Note correction to the regular expression.

Comment: OK, I see. Thx!